# read pdf from itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I had made a table in pdf using text in java web application.

PDF Generated is:

Gender | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3

---

Male   | 1845     | 645      |  254

Female | 214      | 457      | 142

On reading pdf i used following code:

ArrayList allrows = firstable.getRows();

```
    for (PdfPRow currentrow:allrows) {
        PdfPCell[] allcells = currentrow.getCells(); 
        System.out.println("CurrentRow ->"+currentrow.getCells());
        for(PdfPCell currentcell : allcells){
            ArrayList<Element> element = (ArrayList<Element>) currentcell.getCompositeElements();
            System.out.println("Element->"+element.toString());
        }
    }
```

How to read text from pdf columns and pass to int variables?

Comment: iText is not really made for reading PDF. I would use some other strategy.

Comment: Same here, I had make changes in my java code. So, that reading from pdf would be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate the Column of the pdf as fields, so that reading will be much easier